# React - parse user entered values by commas and remove CR/LF and whitespace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<TextArea>` input that allows a user to enter a comma separated list, that then parses the entered values at each `,`. I'm doing this using a basic `.split()` method. This obviously doesn't cover many scenarios. I also need to account for CR / LF characters (linebreaks, etc) as well as leading and trailing whitespaces.

Also a case in my instance would be; I would not want to add another set of double quotes if the values are already enclosed by them.   i.e. "4456",  "54456" would be treated as such and not sent as ""4456"", ""54456"".

My function that parses the entered values looks like this:

```
  addSelectorValue = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      ({ selectorValues, selectorValue }) => ({
        selectorValues: [...selectorValues, ...selectorValue.split(",")],
        selectorValue: ""
      }),
      () => {
        console.log("Array of selectorValues: ", this.state.selectorValues);
      }
    );
  };
```

Is there a certain library or best practice, like regex, to follow to achieve the situation described above?

I have a sandbox demonstrating my [use case here](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5228pp3kj). If you press the submit button on the form after entering a few values, or ones wrapped in `" "`, you can see the line breaks being submitted.

Comment: So you want a CSV parser?

Comment: I guess so, this looks about right https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse

Comment: What do you mean by "such and not sent as"? Do you want to remove `""` around each separate value after the `split`?

Comment: @Tholle If a value is entered, separated by a comma, as `"4235"` do not wrap it in an extra set of `" "`, like `""4235""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Remove all the new lines by replacing all matches to `/\r?\n|\r/g` with the empty string.
2. `split` the string up into an array with `,` as delimiter.
3. `trim` each substring.
4. Remove surrounding `"` with `.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1")` on each substring.

```
addSelectorValue = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState(({ selectorValues, selectorValue }) => ({
    selectorValues: [
      ...selectorValues,
      ...selectorValue
        .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "")
        .split(",")
        .map(str => str.trim().replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1"))
    ],
    selectorValue: ""
  }));
};
```